# How defects can influence the electrical conductivity of ionic insulator, semiconductor and metals?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics, insulators

Does increasing defects increase the conductivity of the insulator?
The band gap between the conduction band and valence band is large such that electrons cannot flow in-between. Shouldn't increasing the number of defects have no effect on electrical conductivity?

Metal decreases conductivity as defects are a source of resistance.

Comment: Way too broad a question.

Comment: Does increasing valency increase conductivity in insulator? (I think it doesn't as electron doesn't have enough energy to flow through valence band to conduction bad.It doesn't matter whether its Schottky or Frenkel defect, its conductivity remain unchanged.)

Comment: What do you mean by 'increasing valency'?

Comment: Vacancies** ( Interstitials and vacancies)

Comment: Consider how some oxygen sensors work - the conductivity changes with oxygen partial pressure because it changers the point defect populations (and the charged point defects are the predominant carriers).

Comment: I am sorry but I don`t understand. (Any source? ) Maybe simply it.

Comment: https://secure.lambdapower.co.uk/TechNotes/Tech-7.asp or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_sensor have some info.